# Azure Function App Error - System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

When I access a particular function app on azure, I am getting this error of exception type: System.InvalidOperationException

[image]

Details of the error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand+<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__164_0
System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2[[System.__Canon System.Private.CoreLib][System.__Canon System.Private.CoreLib]].InnerInvoke
System.Threading.Tasks.Task+<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand+<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__17.MoveNext
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand+<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__17.MoveNext
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand+<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__17.MoveNext
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1+AsyncEnumerator+<InitializeReaderAsync>d__18[[System.__Canon System.Private.CoreLib]].MoveNext
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy+<ExecuteImplementationAsync>d__31`2[[System.Boolean System.Private.CoreLib][System.Boolean System.Private.CoreLib]].MoveNext
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ExecutionStrategy+<ExecuteImplementationAsync>d__31`2[[System.Boolean System.Private.CoreLib][System.Boolean System.Private.CoreLib]].MoveNext
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1+AsyncEnumerator+<MoveNextAsync>d__17[[System.__Canon System.Private.CoreLib]].MoveNext
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor+<SingleOrDefaultAsync>d__22`1[[System.__Canon System.Private.CoreLib]].MoveNext
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ShapedQueryCompilingExpressionVisitor+<SingleOrDefaultAsync>d__22`1[[System.__Canon System.Private.CoreLib]].MoveNext
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[[System.__Canon System.Private.CoreLib]].GetResult
XXXXXXXX.MiddleTier.Functions.CommandProcessor.Handlers.CreatePolicy.CreatePolicy_DeletePolicyInAms+<Run>d__3.MoveNext
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
System.Threading.Tasks.Task+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__139_1
System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback+<>c.<.cctor>b__6_0
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunForThreadPoolUnsafe[[System.__Canon System.Private.CoreLib]]
System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.Execute
System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback
```

I took a close look at where this error is happening and it looks like it is coming from this azure function: `XXXXXXXX.MiddleTier.Functions.CommandProcessor.Handlers.CreatePolicy.CreatePolicy_DeletePolicyInAms`

When I look at the code, it looks like this activity call is placed inside of an exception:

```
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.StepFailed(ex, currentStep);

        var (customer, policy) = await ctx.CallActivityAsync<(Customer, Policy)>(nameof(CreatePolicy_GetLoggingData), command);
        log.Notify(customer, policy);

        --> await ctx.CallActivityAsync(nameof(CreatePolicy_DeletePolicyInAms), command);
        
        throw;
    }
```

I am not sure if it a good practice to call an activity function inside the exception block. This code was not written by me. Can you please advise how I can resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like CreatePolicy_DeletePolicyInAms is not valid name

Answer (score 0):

After digging in your stack trace, I suspect that `.SingleOrDefaultAsync` is being used in your `XXXXXXXX.MiddleTier.Functions.CommandProcessor.Handlers.CreatePolicy.CreatePolicy_DeletePolicyInAms` function.

If there are > 1 results in `.SingleOrDefaultAsync`'s query, this message is thrown. *This is actually a bad error message and has been reported several time in the past.* You can raise this issue [here](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/19639) or open a new GitHub issue to address the same. *But, note that the behavior is right as per the definition of the method.*:

> Asynchronously returns the only element of a sequence that satisfies a
> specified condition or a default value if no such element exists; this
> method throws an exception if more than one element satisfies the
> condition.

Let me know if you have follow-up questions.